# My MIPS assembler won't run with the test.asm file in the project folder

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I have an input file test.asm

```
.data
.integer 120
.dbyte 8
.integer 121
.text

addi $1,$0,10
lw $2,123($4)
sw $3,4($1)
add $10,$0,$0
sub $11,$0,$0
sll $4,$4,10
lui $5,123
slt $10,$0,$0
ori $11,$0,10
addu $6,$10,$13
```

It is supposed to run through my MIPS assembler code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// synthesized missing definitions ...
#if 1
#define TEXT_SEGMENT 0x0200
#define DATA_SEGMENT 0x0000
#define MAX_SIZE    1024

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int n;
    int size;
} Directive;

Directive directives[1000];

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int opcode;
    int funct;
} Instruction;

Instruction instructions[1000];

#endif

// forward function declarations
#if 1
void assemble(char *filename, int *text_segment, int *data_segment);
Instruction *getInstruction(char *instruction);
Directive *getDirective(char *directive);
int getRegisterNumber(char *regis);
int parseInstruction(char *instruction, int *opcode, int *funct);
int parseDirective(char *directive, int *type, int *size);
#endif

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Checking command line arguments
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <test.asm> <test.out>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    // Initializing memory
    int text_segment[MAX_SIZE];
    int data_segment[MAX_SIZE];

// NOTE/BUG: compiler warns about third arg being too small
#if 0
    memset(text_segment, 0, MAX_SIZE);
    memset(data_segment, 0, MAX_SIZE);
#else
    memset(text_segment, 0, sizeof(text_segment));
    memset(data_segment, 0, sizeof(data_segment));
#endif

    // Writing to output file
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    fwrite(text_segment, 1, MAX_SIZE, fp);
    fwrite(data_segment, 1, MAX_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

// Assembling the input file
void
assemble(char *filename, int *text_segment, int *data_segment)
{
// NOTE/BUG: line_number not used
#if 0
    int line_number = 0;
#endif
    int text_offset = 0;
    int data_offset = 0;
    char line[256];
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(line, 256, fp)) {
        // Handling blank lines
        if (strcmp(line, "\n") == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Parsing line
// NOTE/BUG: compiler warning: label set but not used
        char *label = NULL;
        char *instruction = NULL;
        char *directive = NULL;
        char *operands = NULL;

        label = strtok(line, ":");
        instruction = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
        directive = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
        operands = strtok(NULL, "\n\t");

        // Handling instructions
        if (instruction) {
            // Parsing instruction
            int opcode = 0;
            int funct = 0;
            int rs = 0;
            int rt = 0;
            int rd = 0;
            int imm = 0;
            int add = 0;

            if (parseInstruction(instruction, &opcode, &funct)) {
                rs = getRegisterNumber(strtok(operands, ","));
                rt = getRegisterNumber(strtok(NULL, ","));
                if (opcode == 0) {
                    rd = getRegisterNumber(strtok(NULL, ","));
                }
                else {
                    imm = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
                }
                // Generating machine code
                int machine_code = 0;

                machine_code |= (opcode << 26);
                machine_code |= (rs << 21);
                machine_code |= (rt << 16);
                machine_code |= (rd << 11);
                machine_code |= (imm << 0);
                machine_code |= (add << 0);
                machine_code |= (funct << 0);
                // Writing machine code to text segment
                text_segment[text_offset] = machine_code;
                text_offset += 1;
            }
            // Handling directives
            if (directive) {
                // Parsing directive
                int type = 0;
                int size = 0;

                if (parseDirective(directive, &type, &size)) {
                    char *token = strtok(operands, ",");

                    while (token) {
                        int value = 0;

                        sscanf(token, "%d", &value);

                        // Handling .dbyte
                        if (type == 2) {
// NOTE/BUG: statement with no effect
#if 0
                            data_segment;
#endif
                            // Writing value to data segments
                            data_segment[data_offset] = value;
                            data_offset += 1;
                        }

                        // Handling .integer
                        if (type == 3) {
                            // Writing value to data segment
                            data_segment[data_offset] = value;
                            data_offset += 1;
                        }

                        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }
}

// Getting MIPS instruction
Instruction *
getInstruction(char *instruction)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (instructions[i].name) {
        if (strcmp(instructions[i].name, instruction) == 0) {
            return &instructions[i];
        }

        i++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

// Getting MIPS directive
Directive *
getDirective(char *directive)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (directives[i].name) {
        if (strcmp(directives[i].name, directive)) {
            return &directives[i];
        }

        i++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

// Getting register number
int
getRegisterNumber(char *regis)
{
    int reg = 0;

    sscanf(regis, "$%d", &reg);
    return reg;
}

// Parsing instruction
int
parseInstruction(char *instruction, int *opcode, int *funct)
{
    for (int i = 0; instructions[i].name; i++) {
        if (strcmp(instruction, instructions[i].name) == 0) {
            *opcode = instructions[i].opcode;
            *funct = instructions[i].funct;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Parsing directive
int
parseDirective(char *directive, int *type, int *size)
{
    Directive *dir = getDirective(directive);

    if (dir) {
        *type = dir->n;
        *size = dir->size;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm having difficulty getting it to work properly and read the input above in order to write out to a binary output with the instructions given.

Comment: An [mcve] needs to describe what actually happened (instead of what you wanted).  Like what known bugs or unfinished parts still exist?  Also, you have some `#if 0` parts with obviously (to me) buggy things, like a `memset` that only does 1024 bytes instead of 1024 int objects (usually 4 bytes per int).  Is that what you weren't sure of?  And `data_segment;` on a line by itself of course does nothing; there's no operator, IDK what you were hoping to happen on that line.

Comment: Is `.dbyte` supposed to be like `.byte`, assembling one byte into the output in the current section, or I guess only into the data section?  If so, you shouldn't be storing a whole `int`.  Probably your `data_section` should be a `char` array, and use `memcpy(&data_section[data_offset], &value,  1 or 4)` with the size depending on the size of the data element.  (This assumes your C program runs on a host where `int` is also 4 bytes, same as MIPS.  Use `uint32_t` and `uint8_t`, and `sizeof(uint32_t)` etc. to require that.

Comment: It is a lot of code about which to just ask "it does not work, why?".  That would be to ask us to debug your whole program, from scratch with no prior information on the expected output and actual output.  You would do better to narrow down an issue by performing debugging.  Using a debugger you are likely to be able to solve the problem yourself in any case and it is an essential tool for developing any non-trivial C application, you would do better to learn to use a debugger than to ask questions about code to be debugged.

Comment: Or if not debug it yourself, to reduce it to a generic question about C, like how to copy a byte into an `int` array, which you could try to search for answers for.  (To which the answer is: don't do that, make your data_section an array of bytes and do wider accesses with `memcpy`.)

Comment: The first error is that it is having trouble creating an output file with the error 

Usage: ./a.out <test.asm> <test.out>

Comment: Also, it is having difficulty  reading my input file "test.asm"